# Behavior difference when building TF Keras RNN with two different methods

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am building a RNN text generator, mostly going from the Tensorflow docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation).

My question, I have defined the model two ways:

Method (1):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim,
                                  batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
        tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, stateful=True,
                            recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
    ])
```

Method (2):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim,
                                    batch_input_shape=[BATCH_SIZE, None]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units, return_sequences=True,
                              stateful=True,
                              recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size))
```

In my mind, these both do the same thing. However when generating text with:

```
def generate_text(model, start_string, length=1000):
    # converting start string to numbers (vectorisation)
    input_eval = [char2idx[s] for s in start_string]
    input_eval = tf.expand_dims(input_eval, 0)

    # initialise empty string to store results
    text = []

    model.reset_states()
    for i in range(length):
        predictions = model(input_eval)
        # remove batch dimension
        predictions = tf.squeeze(predictions, 0)

        # use categorical distribution to predict character returned by model
        predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()

        # we pass the predicted character as the next input to the model
        # along with previous hidden state
        input_eval = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)

        # append predicted text
        text.append(idx2char[predicted_id])

    return (start_string + ''.join(text))
```

Which I pass:

```
print(generate_text(model, start_string=u'From '))
```

Method (1) works perfectly, but method (2) throws the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape Tensor("embedding_1_input:0", shape=(64, None), dtype=float32) for input (64, None), but it was re-called on a Tensor with incompatible shape (1, 5).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-eb814780c9fe> in <module>()
----> 1 print(generate_text(model, start_string=u'From ', length=PRINT))

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in set_shape(self, shape)
   1086       raise ValueError(
   1087           "Tensor's shape %s is not compatible with supplied shape %s" %
-> 1088           (self.shape, shape))
   1089 
   1090   # Methods not supported / implemented for Eager Tensors.

ValueError: Tensor's shape (5, 64, 1024) is not compatible with supplied shape [5, 1, 1024]
```

If anyone could help me understand what the difference is between these two methods that would be amazing, thankyou!

Edit:
Including model saving and loading code. I use this to save the model (with a batch size 64) and then load with a batch size of 1 for text generation.
Saving weights:

```
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath='./training_checkpoints/ckpt_{epoch}',
    save_weights_only=True
)
```

Loading weights into new model (batch size = 1):

```
model = build_model(len(vocab_char), EMBED_DIM, UNITS, 1)
model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./training_checkpoints'))
model.build(tf.TensorShape([1, None]))
model.summary()
```

Comment: Have a look at your BATCH_SIZE(in second) and batch_size(in first) variables? are they the same?

Comment: Batch size during training is 64, then for text generation is 1. This is my first time with text generation so I'm not sure if that's absolutely necessary but it is the same as what is done in the tf docs. As I understand, this is why we rebuild the network (this wasn't mentioned before), so that we predict on a single batch rather than 64. I'll edit the question to include this part of the code. Thanks